# Does user_dim.first_open_timestamp_micros change when app updated or reinstalled?

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics

In the official document of [Firebase](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7029846?hl=en), there is a description about the **user_dim.first_open_timestamp_micros**

> The time (in microseconds) at which the user first opened the app.

I wonder after the app updated or reinstalled, does this value change?

---

UPDATE: I have do some experiments with Google Firebase and make sure the property will change as @djabi answered when app is uninstalled or reinstalled but not change when app is updated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the app is uninstalled and reinstalled both `user_dim.first_open_timestamp_micros` and `user_dim.app_info.app_instance_id` change. Updating the app to new version does not change `user_dim.first_open_timestamp_micros` or `user_dim.app_info.app_instance_id`.

Comment: Thank you, @djabi. From the [official doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/iid/FirebaseInstanceId), the `app_instance_id` will change on four situations. Is the `first_open_timestamp_micros` will also change on these four situations?